# Spring Security using Bcrypt and hibernate returning bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

As the title says, I'm using Spring Security with JWT (using hibernate and bCrypt) to sign up users and let them login. I've followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) to make this work in my project. When doing exactly the same as the tutorial (using the in-memory-database) everythings seems to work fine.  But when intergrating the code in my own project the authentication keeps failing, giving a "bad credentials" exception.

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApiApplication {

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

My websecurity config looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                   BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

}

The authentication filter, whenever I try to send a post with the username and password, the unsuccessfulAuthentication runs, even with correct credentials.

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("This method never runs...");
    Claims claims = Jwts.claims()
            .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME));

    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
            .compact();

    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    System.out.println("FAILED");
    failed.printStackTrace(); // bad creds
}
}
```

UserDetailServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private UserRepository repository;

public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
    this.repository = applicationUserRepository;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = repository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        System.out.println("User is null");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), emptyList());
}
}
```

The user entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_entity")
public class User implements Serializable {

public User() { }

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true)
private long userId;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "username", unique = true)
private String username;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "user_rol")
@JsonProperty("userRol")
private String userRol;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
}
```

In my user controller I encrypt the password like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public User signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setUserRol("ADMIN");
    return userService.signUpUser(user);
}
```

Everythings seems to be ok, Spring succesfully puts a new user in the database (with an encrypted password), whenever I do a login attempt it also succesfully gets that user, but authentication still fails (with correct credentials ofcourse). So my guess there is something wrong with the bcypt password encoder...

Another thing I wonder; where does the /login route come from? Is this a default route within Spring Security? (I've never declared it)

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is due a typo in your attemptAuthentication() method.

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
try {
    User creds = new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

    return authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    creds.getUsername(),
                    creds.getUsername(),
                    new ArrayList<>())
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

}

In the constructor of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken the second argument should be creds.getPassword() and not creds.getUsername().

Comment: Oh my god... took me 2 days. Thanks!